# Accessing text file created within a function inside another function

Tags: python, file

I have a function setup in the following manner:

```
@MyClass
def func1():
    #runs a bash script
    subprocess.call(shlex.split('./fedora.sh ./all_packages.txt'))
    
    #creates a text file called log.txt

#class method
def func2():
    #How to access log.txt within this class method here?
    
    with open('./log.txt','r'): #returns FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] 
                               #No such file or directory: './log.txt'
        ...
```

How do I access the file created inside `func1` within `func2`? Thanks!

Comment: where is the file created? in the same directory where this python script is?

Comment: @AndrewRyan Yeah, in the  same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way of accessing the newly created file:

```
import os
os.listdir(), key=lambda t: -os.stat(t).st_mtime)[0]
#sorts the files created in desccending order and take the newly created file
```